# TextEdit: RTF to PDF: a hyperlink issue

Tags: macos, mac, textedit

As we know we can add a hyperlink into our `.rtf` documents.
How to ask TextEdit to generate PDF with hyperlinks that are *visible* (blue colour and underline style)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is manually color and underline the link in question. The link is still clickable after you export it to pdf, regardless of whether or not you format it, but if you do, it will maintain the color and other general formatting you give it, making it look the way you want it to.